# How to solve python's NameError: name 'xx' is not defined?

Tags: python

I am learning python, according to the logic written in the code in the book, I want to see the running result, the code is as follows, but the output error `NameError: name 'pr' is not defined`

code show as below:

```py
stack=[]
def pushit():
    stack:append(input(' Enter New String: ').strip())
def popit():
    if len(stack)==0:
        print('Cannot pop from an empty stack!')
    else:
        print ('Removes [','stack.pop()',']')
def viewstack():
    print(stack)
CMDs={'u':pushit,'o':popit,'v':viewstack}
def showmenu():
    pr=''' 
p(U)sh
p(O)p
(V)iew
(Q)uit
Enter choice:'''
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            choice=input(pr).strip()[0].lower()
        except (EOFError,KeyboardInterrupt,IndexError):
            choice='q'
        print('\nYou picked:[%s]'%choice)
        if choice not in 'uovq':
            print('Invalid option,try again')
        else:
            break
        if choice=='q':
            break
        CMDs[choice]()
if _name_=='_main_':
    showmenu()
```

The error message is as follows：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zego/Desktop/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    choice=input(pr).strip()[0].lower()
NameError: name 'pr' is not defined
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, start your indentation right after `def`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not inserted the `showmenu` function code at right index. The `while` loop should be started from `one tab` space ahead.

**Look at the below code.**

```
stack=[]
def pushit():
    stack:append(input(' Enter New String: ').strip())
def popit():
    if len(stack)==0:
        print('Cannot pop from an empty stack!')
    else:
        print ('Removes [','stack.pop()',']')
def viewstack():
    print(stack)
CMDs={'u':pushit,'o':popit,'v':viewstack}
def showmenu():
    pr=''' 
p(U)sh
p(O)p
(V)iew
(Q)uit
Enter choice:'''
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                choice=input(pr).strip()[0].lower()
            except (EOFError,KeyboardInterrupt,IndexError):
                choice='q'
            print('\nYou picked:[%s]'%choice)
            if choice not in 'uovq':
                print('Invalid option,try again')
            else:
                break
            if choice=='q':
                break
            CMDs[choice]()
```